# Does explicit requestfocus call needs a explicit clearfocus call for that view?

Tags: android

I just wanted to understand that is it mandatory to provide a clearfocus call for every requestfocus call on a view. For Example, I have two edittexts if i request focus on first edittext do i have to explicitly call clearfocus whenever my other edittext gets a focus. I checked the documentation but they have not mentioned explicitly about the same. It would be great if someone can help me in understanding the same.

Thanks,
Rupesh

Comment: I hadn't called clearFocus() and it worked fine for me

Comment: @Shreya : Thanks for this piece of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly clear the focus of items. Android itself will automatically clear the focus of items, when another item in the view got focus.